# Asus PC boot failure

Tags: boot, laptop, hardware-failure, laptop-repair, asus

My Asus PC (a Rog Strix G15) suddenly switched off and refused to boot back again. No boot, no lights, not even charge light when connected to power. Nothing has happened to it, it just suddenly happened (but I must add that a couple of months before this problem I opened up the PC to insert a second SSD for dual booting purposes, but after the operation the laptop booted up with no issues, and this problem is happening one month later, so I don't think it has much to do with it).
After a while, like 15 minutes, I tried to turn it back again and it actually responded! Lights lit up, the keyboard lit up, but the screen remained black. I tried to shut it off and on again, but same behaviour, the screen remains black even if the computer seems to turn on.

What is happening? Why it completely died only to turn to life partially 15 minutes later? How do I solve the problem? The computer is still completely unusable since the screen remains completely black.

Comment: Your issues are not linked to the installation of an SSD weeks or months ago. When I had similar problem on a laptop, the motherboard and cable connected to the display, had to be replaced

Comment: Could also be the power supply. A repair-shop is indicated.